# combinatorics :: selecting from variety of groups

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

in how many ways one or more than one fruit can be selected from 6 varieties of fruits given that there are 5 fruits of each variety?

**MY TRY :**

i dont have any clue so i am giving my thoughts

**MY THOUGHTS :**

no. of. fruits can be selected is :(1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or ......... or 30(=6*5))

selecting 1 : any one of 6 i.e 6C1

selecting 2 : two from different variety or two from same 6c1 + 6C2

selecting 3 : 6C1 + 6C2*6C1 + 6C3

....... in this fashion ... but i dont think this is correct approach because how will we decide it for large no. for exam selecting 15 ... and other reason is it going to be very very lengthy answer.... but this is a mutiple choice question.. time allotted for each question is 2.5 minutes

Comment: please help ...... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on exactly what's meant by "one or more than one."  Does it mean at least one of *each* fruit, or does it mean at least one of *some* fruit?  If it means *each*, then the answer is $5^6$.  If it means *some*, then the answer is $6^6-1$.  Here's why:

Each different selection amounts to saying how many of each fruit (apples, bananas, etc.) you pick.  For each of the $6$ varieties of fruit, that number either varies from $1$ to $5$ if "one or more than one" refers to *each* fruit, or from $0$ to $5$ if it means *some* fruit, with the understanding that the numbers can't *all* be $0$.  In the former case, you simply get $5^6$.  In the latter case, you start with $6^6$, but that includes the "empty" selection, so you need to subtract $1$.